# Java - JPA - creating counts per month increments

Tags: java, json, jpa

I am trying to create the json structure that will power a line chart showing the member count per month.

[image]

The table looks like this.

```
id  |  email            | registeredDate
1   |  email1@test.com  | 2017-09-04
2   |  email2@test.com  | 2017-09-14
3   |  email3@test.com  | 2017-09-21
4   |  email4@test.com  | 2017-10-01
5   |  email5@test.com  | 2017-10-03
6   |  email6@test.com  | 2017-10-12
7   |  email7@test.com  | 2017-10-15
8   |  email8@test.com  | 2017-10-16
9   |  email9@test.com  | 2017-11-06
10  |  email10@test.com | 2017-11-07
11  |  email11@test.com | 2017-12-02
```

So the json structure to try and create this kind of chart would look something like the following

```
[   
    {
        "value": 3,
        "date": "2017-09-01"
    },
    {
        "value": 8,
        "date": "2017-10-01"
    },
    {
        "value": 10,
        "date": "2017-11-01"
    },
    {
        "value": 11,
        "date": "2017-12-01"
    }
]
```

The issue I am having is how to use or create various JPA queries to build this kind of result.

So here is a JPA that will get a member count between a date range.

```
long countByRegisteredDateBetween(Date thresholdDate1, Date thresholdDate2) throws Exception;
```

it seems a bit hotch potch to find the min and max registered date and frog hop to create this json structure?

```
minReg = 2017-09-04
maxReg = 2017-12-02
```

loop...

```
x = 0;

-------------------------------------------
//count in sep 2017
date1 = "2017-09-01";
date2 = "2017-10-01";
countPerMonth = countByRegisteredDateBetween(date1, date2);

x+=countPerMonth;

JSONObject chartObj = new JSONObject();
chartObj.put("value", x);
chartObj.put("date", date1);
-------------------------------------------

//count in oct 2017
date1 = "2017-10-01";
date2 = "2017-11-01";
countPerMonth = countByRegisteredDateBetween(date1, date2);

x+=countPerMonth;

JSONObject chartObj = new JSONObject();
chartObj.put("value", x);
chartObj.put("date", date1);
-------------------------------------------

//count in nov 2017
date1 = "2017-11-01";
date2 = "2017-12-01";
countPerMonth = countByRegisteredDateBetween(date1, date2);

x+=countPerMonth;

JSONObject chartObj = new JSONObject();
chartObj.put("value", x);
chartObj.put("date", date1);
-------------------------------------------

//count in dec 2017
date1 = "2017-12-01";
date2 = "2018-01-01";
countPerMonth = countByRegisteredDateBetween(date1, date2);
x+=countPerMonth;

JSONObject chartObj = new JSONObject();
chartObj.put("value", x);
chartObj.put("date", date1);
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just use a native query then `select RegisteredDate, count(*) from table where RegisteredDate between ? and ? group by RegisteredDate order by RegisteredDate`

Comment: - Well - there should be a JPA equivalent - this would be the only native query in the repo otherwise.

Comment: see http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group#GROUP_BY_with_Aggregate_Functions_

Comment: By JPA equivalent - do you mean SpringData?  JPA involves the ability to write your own queries

Comment: Sure I suppose - I mean instead of countByRegisteredDateBetween  -- is there something like <list> countByRegisteredDateBetweenGroupByRegisteredDateOrderByRegisteredDate(date1, date2)  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: "ByRegisteredDateBetween"  "OrderByRegisteredDateAsc"

Comment: "here is a JPA " Huh? That is a method name for Spring Data JPA (!= JPA API)

Comment: I'd create a database view which aggregates the data and map an Entity to that view.